# PIVOT в MS SQL использовать без агрегатной функции

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, содержит следующие данные :
[image: Результат запроса]

Eсть еще один столбец id он уникальный, но он не участвует в select.

Мне необходимо получить результат в одну строку, где первый столбец `shiftcode` все остальные это от 0 до 5 со значениями которые указаны в столбце arrivedTime. Я пробую сделать так :

```
SELECT shiftcode, [0], [1], [2] FROM newRegistr 
PIVOT( max(arrivedTime)
  FOR newRegistr.sort
  IN ([0], [1], [2])

  )AS test
WHERE shiftCode = '4168428'
```

Получаю :
[image: Второй результат]

Что можно сделать? Цель - не использовать 6 под запросов.

Comment: Ну раз у Вас запись единственная, то использование любой групповой функции (например, MAX) ничем не повредит...

Comment: Ваш запрос должен выдавать одну строчку (по крайней мере он выдает одну у меня на таких же данных). Вы точно результаты того запроса привели в вопросе? :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW1g8.png

Comment: @Akina я же вроде ее и использую, он почему NULL плодит, наверно из за ID.

Comment: @PashaPash да, но там есть еще один столбец id он уникальный, но он же не участвует в select почему так происходит не пойму, неужели прийдется плодить временную таблицу

Comment: @PashaPash после того как результат первого звпроса я залил во временную таблицу а потом уже работал со временно таблице тогда все ок. Что же у меня на костылях :(

Comment: @Winteriscoming можно же подзапросом сделать. или через CTE

Comment: а `where sort in (0,1,2)`  не надо сделать?

Comment: @teran не надо.

Comment: @PashaPash а с точки зрения эффективности на большом объеме? То есть я понимаю, что это не влияет не результат. но отфильтровать то данные не помешает прежде чем кормить пивоту

Comment: @teran зависит от индексов. там фильтр по shiftcode, так что конкретно в случае топикастера - не нужно. в общем случае - да, стоило бы вписать, и проверить на наличие индекса. И, желательно, вписать условие как < 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делайте PIVOT только на основе тех данных, которые участвуют в целевой выборке:

```
SELECT shiftcode, [0], [1], [2] FROM 
(
    SELECT shiftcode, sort, arrivedTime FROM newRegistr
    WHERE shiftCode = '4168428' -- можно переставить ниже
) as rec
PIVOT( max(arrivedTime)
  FOR rec.sort
  IN ([0], [1], [2])

  )AS test
```

или через CTE:

```
;with RecordsToPivot as
(
    SELECT shiftcode, sort, arrivedTime FROM newRegistr
    WHERE shiftCode = '4168428' -- можно переставить ниже
)
SELECT shiftcode, [0], [1], [2] FROM RecordsToPivot
PIVOT( max(arrivedTime)
  FOR RecordsToPivot.sort
  IN ([0], [1], [2])

  )AS test
```